# Numeric.Probability.Monad not exported from probability package and therefore examples don't work?

Tags: haskell, probability, cabal, ghci

I was playing around with the [probability](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/probability/0.2.4/doc/html/Numeric-Probability-Distribution.html) package, trying to understand how the various examples work.  A number of the examples import Numeric.Probability.Monad which is hidden it seems and therefore means I can't run the examples.

[Monty Hall Example](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/probability/0.2.4/doc/html/src/Numeric-Probability-Example-MontyHall.html#Door):

```
module Numeric.Probability.Example.MontyHall where

import qualified Numeric.Probability.Distribution as Dist
import qualified Numeric.Probability.Transition as Trans
import Numeric.Probability.Simulation ((~.), )

import Numeric.Probability.Percentage
    (Dist, RDist, Trans, )

import qualified Numeric.Probability.Monad as MonadExt
```

And If i try to run it in ghci

```
:load "MontyHall.hs"

MontyHall.hs:10:18:
    Could not find module `Numeric.Probability.Monad'
    it is a hidden module in the package `probability-0.2.4'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong, as what is the point of examples that can't be run.  So what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The only function from `Numeric.Probability.Monad` used in the `MontyHall` file is this one:

```
compose :: Monad m => [a -> m a] -> a -> m a
compose = foldl (flip (<=<)) return
```

It's a straightforward helper function, and you can just inline it yourself.

Comment: So there is nothing I am doing wrong, I just have to inline whatever functions from Numeric.Probability.Monad that whatever example uses, like [this one](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/probability/0.2.4/doc/html/src/Numeric-Probability-Example-Collection.html#Collection) uses do while and so on. I thought I was missing an import or something.

Comment: I think its a quirk of the package -- that file just has some helper functions, so since it is for "internal" use it does not get exported. But the helper functions are handy enough to use in examples. So, whoops!